# Need Explanation of this code

Tags: c, algorithm, math, expression

The code outputs number of pairs of (i,j) which satisfy the condition

```
(2^j-1) % (2^i-1) == 0
```

where the

```
1<=i<j<=n
```

n is the number user input under which number of (i,j) pairs are to be found.
Code works perfectly, but what is the logic behind this code is hard to understand.

P.S: t is a variable which will let user to input numbers more than one at a time.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    int main()
    {   
        int t;
        long n,sum,ans; 
        scanf("%d",&t);
        while(t--)
        {
            scanf("%ld",&n);
            int nrt=(int)sqrt(n);
            sum=0;
            for(int i=1;i<=nrt;i++)
            {
                 sum+=n/i;
            }
            ans=2*sum-nrt*nrt-n;
            printf("%ld\n",ans);
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What's hard?  `2^j` is an xor operation which toggles the 2-bit; the -1 subtracts one from that.  There's a similar operation for the RHS of the `%` operator.  The `%` operator gives the remainder when the LHS is divided by the RHS.  But, having looked at the code, I'm puzzled — what relevance does the question about `(2^j-1) % (2^i-1) == 0` have to the code that is shown?  Is that another way of calculating the same result?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The OP almost certainly is using "^" in that condition (which is not C code) to represent exponentiation. " Is that another way of calculating the same result?" -- The OP said "The code outputs number of pairs of (i,j) which satisfy the condition ..." -- that's a clear statement of the relationship.

Comment: Prateek: it would be best to ask the person who wrote the code. They could probably provide you with a mathematical article that proves this solution to the given problem. Working out such a proof is probably not trivial.

Comment: "t is a variable which will let user to input numbers more than one at a time" -- it would be far better to loop as long as the scanf for `n` succeeds.

Comment: Compile your program with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Take into account the return value of `scanf` (it is the number of successfully scanned items). **Use a debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a brute-force approach to the problem and print the results*:

```
 #############################   2^^1 -1 == 1
  -#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#   2^^2 -1  == 3
   --#--#--#--#--#--#--#--#--#   2^^3 -1  == 7
    ---#---#---#---#---#---#--   2^^4 -1  == 15
     ----#----#----#----#----#   2^^5 -1  == 31
      -----#-----#-----#-----#   2^^6 -1  == 63
       ------#------#------#--   2^^7 -1  == 127
        -------#-------#------   2^^8 -1  == 255
         --------#--------#---   2^^9 -1  == 511
          ---------#---------#   2^^10 -1 == 1023
           ----------#--------   2^^11 -1 == 2047
            -----------#------   2^^12 -1 == 4095
             ------------#----   2^^13 -1 == 8191
              -------------#--   2^^14 -1 == 16383
               --------------#   2^^15 -1 == 32767
                --------------   2^^16 -1 == 65535
                 -------------   2^^17 -1 == 131071
                           ...   ...
```

A hash mark denotes the cases where your condition is met. A nice pattern emerges: Every one of your numbers is divisible by 1, every other is divisible by 3, every third is divisible by 7 and so on. Every `i`th number is divisible by `2^^i - 1`.**

With this insight, we can code your function as:

```
int f(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) sum += (n - i) / i;

    return sum;
}
```

We can substitute `(n - i) / i` with `n / i - 1` and move the common subtrahend `-1` into the return value:

```
int g(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) sum += n / i;

    return sum - n;
}
```

Now let's look at the sum `∑(1, n: n / i)`. For example:

```
∑(i = 1, 9: 9 / i) = 9 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

We can get at the same sum by looking at it from right to left and by counting how often each summand occurs:

```
∑(i = 1, 9: 9 / i) = 5*1 + 1*2 + 1*3 + 1*4 + 1*9
```

We can get at this representation easily:

```
∑(i = 1, n: n / i) = ∑(1, n: i * (n / i - n / (i + 1))
```

This really is just another way to write the sum; you can see that by grouping the summands differently, so that they share the same denominator:

```
∑(i = 1, N: i * (n / i - n / (i + 1))
    = n + ∑(i = 1, n: ((i + 1) - i)  * n / (i + 1))
    = n + ∑(i = 1, n: n / (i + 1)) - (N + 1) * (n / (N + 1))
    = n + ∑(i = 2, n + 1: n / i) - c
    = ∑(i = 1, n: n / i) - c
```

The additional term `c = (N + 1) * (n / (N + 1))` is a correction term because only half of the term for `i = n + 1` is used. When summing over the whole range, `n / (n + 1)` is zero and vanishes. It doesn't vanish when summing only part of the array, as we'll see later.

If we split the sum into a head and tail at `s = sqrt(n)`, we get:

```
∑(i = 1, n: n / i) = ∑(i = 1, s: n / i) + ∑(s + 1, n: n / i)
```

Let's represent the head in the original fashion and the tail in the "count the summands" fashion, for example:

```
∑(i = 1, 9: 9 / i) = (9 + 4 + 3)   +   (5*1 + 1*2)
```

For any `n`:

```
∑(i = 1, n: n / i) 
    = ∑(i = 1, s: n / i) + ∑(1, s - 1: i * (n / i - n / (i + 1))
    = ∑(i = 1, s: n / i) + ∑(1, s: n / i) - s * (n / s)
```

All divisions are integer divisions (and that's why there have to be parentheses sometimes) and `n / s == s`, so:

```
∑(1, n: n / i) = ∑(i = 1, s: n / i) + ∑(i = 1, s: n / i) - s * (n / s)
               = 2 * ∑(i = 1, s: n / i) - s²
```

And that yields your original function:

```
int h(int n)
{
    int nrt = sqrt(n);
    int sum = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i <= nrt; i++) sum += n/i;

    return 2 * sum - nrt * nrt - n;
}
```

where `∑(1, n: n / i)` in `g` above has been replaced with `2 * ∑(i = 1, s: n / i) - s²`.

*) I've stolen [D's power operator](http://wiki.dlang.org/Operator_precedence) `^^` here, in order not to confuse the old C buffs who take `^` at face value, i.e. as xor.

**) I don't know, *why* the pattern shows. There is probably a good explanation, but for now, I trust my pattern-matching skills. Blindly. **Edit** @nevets's answer has the explanation for this pattern.

Comment: It would be more correct if you edit your output list from `2^^1  == 1` to `2^^1 - 1 == 1` ;)

Comment: @Jongware: Ouch! That comes from being smug about operators and not paying attention to the rest. I'll edit.

Comment: @nevets: Thanks for the explanation, I've cross-referred to your solution.

Comment: oh sorry the previous answer didn't generalize to a general case, which is (2^(nk) - 1). See my revised answer for more details :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a very interesting problem. If you tried some small inputs, you will get a rough idea on the code.

I used a very simple code to generate all valid pairs when `n = 10`, and here is what I got:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 9
1 10
2 4
2 6
2 8
2 10
3 6
3 9
4 8
5 10
```

Surprise? We could see a very obvious pattern here: when `i, j` satisfies `j = k * i`, where `k` is an integer and `j = k * i < n`, `i, j` is a valid pair. It's totally nothing to do with the original equation, only depends on `n`.

Actually this is not surprise, **since** `(2^(nk) - 1) = ((2^k)^n - 1) = (a^n - 1)`, where `a = 2^k`, **therefore we could apply [factoring rule](http://www.mathwords.com/f/factoring_rules.htm)**, which gives `(a^n - 1) = (a - 1)(a^(n - 1) + a^(n - 2) + .. + 1)`, and thus could be factorized by `(a - 1)`, i.e. `(2^(nk) - 1) % (2^k - 1) == 0`.

Now the problem becomes how to count this number efficiently. By the condition, we have `j > i`. Previous we know `j = k * i`. Therefore, `k` must be in the range of `[2, n / i]`. For each `i`, we have totally `(n / i) - 2 + 1 = (n / i) - 1` valid choices for `k`. Therefore, the total valid pairs will be `sigma((n / i) - 1, 1 <= i <= n)`.

As for how to transform the equation into the code you gave, please refer to @MOehm's answer.

Comment: Ah, very good! You've found the explanation for the pattern that I have only seen, but could not explain. It's very obvious now.

Comment: @MOehm I think we arrived to the same solution using different approach :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable i works from 1 to nrt, nrt being the square root of n `converted explicitily into an int value`. Each time the loop works, sum is added by the result of (n/i). The code then prints the `ans` (long type) with is calculated as (twice the sum-nrt square-n).

Comment: The OP is asking why that computation yields the desired result.